# create new two cols by apply() with one old col

Tags: python, pandas

the min Example

```
exonbed=pd.DataFrame(['NM_1234','NM_123456','NM_1234567'],columns =['trid'])
gene_trid_reverse={'NM_1234':'gene1','NM_123456':'gene2'}
```

i try

```
exonbed[['gene','isMANE']]=exonbed['trid'].apply(lambda x : (gene_trid_reverse[x],'MANE' if x in  gene_trid_reverse else x,'NO MANE') ,result_type='expand' )
```

erro

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'
```

I also try，

```
exonbed['gene_isMANE']=exonbed['trid'].apply(lambda x : (gene_trid_reverse[x],'MANE') if x in  gene_trid_reverse else (x,'NO MANE'))

exonbed['gene']=exonbed['gene_isMANE'].str.split(',')[0]
exonbed['isMANE']=exonbed['gene_isMANE'].str.split(',')[1]
```

but i get NA in cols  gene and  isMANE

```
         trid            gene_isMANE  gene  isMANE
0     NM_1234          (gene1, MANE)   NaN     NaN
1   NM_123456          (gene2, MANE)   NaN     NaN
2  NM_1234567  (NM_1234567, NO MANE)   NaN     NaN
```

Perhaps casting it to a string instead of a collection can help? But I would like to know the most direct way to apply.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
L = exonbed['trid'].apply(lambda x : (gene_trid_reverse[x],'MANE')
                                      if x in gene_trid_reverse 
                                      else (x,'NO MANE'))
exonbed[['gene','isMANE']] = pd.DataFrame(L, index=exonbed.index)
```

Or:

```
L = [(gene_trid_reverse[x],'MANE') 
     if x in gene_trid_reverse 
     else (x,'NO MANE') for x in exonbed['trid']]
exonbed[['gene','isMANE']] = pd.DataFrame(L, index=exonbed.index)
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't create a minimum sample before，now I got erro ```ValueError: Columns must be same length as key```

Comment: @tanqiang - If use `df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=exonbed.index)` what is `print (df1.columns)` ?